# Android - Why can't I do add member variables for only BuildConfig.DEBUG builds?

Tags: java, android

This is probably more of a java issue, but shouldn't it be possible to do something like this?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

public TextView text;

if (BuildConfig.DEBUG){
public TextView debugText;
}


//onCreate code
onCreate()...

}
```

Is there any way to get around this? I don't want to have two separate files, but I don't want debug variables to be compiled into the build.

Comment: Why did you accept that answer, did you even see mine? You can change your `TextView` based on the `Build.DEBUG`.

Comment: I want two different reference variables... not two different objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to get around this, you cannot use an if statement here and conditionally define an instance variable that the whole object can use.

Comment: This is not true. See my answer.

Comment: You still define it, no matter if some condition holds or not, but only assign it conditionally, so the variable is still there.

Comment: He could have a production textview vs a debug textview. My code is valid.

Comment: Your answer is correct and definitely better than mine but my answer is still correct, you cannot define/declare the variable conditionally.